# How to animate multiple keyframes on multiple classes in CSS and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to animate two keyframes `bar` and `circle_animation` when this section comes into view, i.e. when the user scrolls down to this section of the page. I can get the `circle_animation` section to work using this:

```
const element = document.querySelector('.skill-container');
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  element.classList.toggle( 'animation_circle', entries[0].isIntersecting );
});
observer.observe( element )
```

However I cannot get the line bars to work. I tried:

```
  const element = document.querySelector('line_content .line_bar');
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
    element.classList.toggle( 'animation_bar', entries[0].isIntersecting );
  });
  observer.observe( element )
```

But this does nothing.

I also want to combine the line bars and the circles so they all animate at the same time.

I tried:

```
  const element = document.querySelectorAll('.skill-container' 'line_content .line_bar');
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
    element.classList.toggle( 'animation_bar', entries[0].isIntersecting );
  });
  observer.observe( element )
```

And

```
  const element = document.querySelectorAll('.skill-container, line_content .line_bar');
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
    element.classList.toggle( 'animation_bar', entries[0].isIntersecting );
  });
  observer.observe( element )
```

But I assume that given the `line_content` is probably incorrect, they both won't work.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<!-- Head -->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cedarville+Cursive&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="skills.css">  
</head>

<!-- Body -->
<body>

<!-- Dummy Section -->
<div class = "dummy">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Odit optio assumenda quidem reprehenderit qui veniam delectus aliquid ipsa? Magnam neque at corrupti aliquid, dolor possimus veniam, eum porro quasi non, impedit accusamus adipisci quis. Aliquam, neque quo dicta totam libero facere tempora eligendi obcaecati odit porro magni quos suscipit veniam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Odit optio assumenda quidem reprehenderit qui veniam delectus aliquid ipsa? Magnam neque at corrupti aliquid, dolor possimus veniam, eum porro quasi non, impedit accusamus adipisci quis. Aliquam, neque quo dicta totam libero facere tempora eligendi obcaecati odit porro magni quos suscipit veniam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Odit optio assumenda quidem reprehenderit qui veniam delectus aliquid ipsa? Magnam neque at corrupti aliquid, dolor possimus veniam, eum porro quasi non, impedit accusamus adipisci quis. Aliquam, neque quo dicta totam libero facere tempora eligendi obcaecati odit porro magni quos suscipit veniam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Odit optio assumenda quidem reprehenderit qui veniam delectus aliquid ipsa? Magnam neque at corrupti aliquid, dolor possimus veniam, eum porro quasi non, impedit accusamus adipisci quis. Aliquam, neque quo dicta totam libero facere tempora eligendi obcaecati odit porro magni quos suscipit veniam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Odit optio assumenda quidem reprehenderit qui veniam delectus aliquid ipsa? Magnam neque at corrupti aliquid, dolor possimus veniam, eum porro quasi non, impedit accusamus adipisci quis. Aliquam, neque quo dicta totam libero facere tempora eligendi obcaecati odit porro magni quos suscipit veniam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Odit optio assumenda quidem reprehenderit qui veniam delectus aliquid ipsa? Magnam neque at corrupti aliquid, dolor possimus veniam, eum porro quasi non, impedit accusamus adipisci quis. Aliquam, neque quo dicta totam libero facere tempora eligendi obcaecati odit porro magni quos suscipit veniam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Odit optio assumenda quidem reprehenderit qui veniam delectus aliquid ipsa? Magnam neque at corrupti aliquid, dolor possimus veniam, eum porro quasi non, impedit accusamus adipisci quis. Aliquam, neque quo dicta totam libero facere tempora eligendi obcaecati odit porro magni quos suscipit veniam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Odit optio assumenda quidem reprehenderit qui veniam delectus aliquid ipsa? Magnam neque at corrupti aliquid, dolor possimus veniam, eum porro quasi non, impedit accusamus adipisci quis. Aliquam, neque quo dicta totam libero facere tempora eligendi obcaecati odit porro magni quos suscipit veniam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Odit optio assumenda quidem reprehenderit qui veniam delectus aliquid ipsa? Magnam neque at corrupti aliquid, dolor possimus veniam, eum porro quasi non, impedit accusamus adipisci quis. Aliquam, neque quo dicta totam libero facere tempora eligendi obcaecati odit porro magni quos suscipit veniam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Odit optio assumenda quidem reprehenderit qui veniam delectus aliquid ipsa? Magnam neque at corrupti aliquid, dolor possimus veniam, eum porro quasi non, impedit accusamus adipisci quis. Aliquam, neque quo dicta totam libero facere tempora eligendi obcaecati odit porro magni quos suscipit veniam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Odit optio assumenda quidem reprehenderit qui veniam delectus aliquid ipsa? Magnam neque at corrupti aliquid, dolor possimus veniam, eum porro quasi non, impedit accusamus adipisci quis. Aliquam, neque quo dicta totam libero facere tempora eligendi obcaecati odit porro magni quos suscipit veniam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Odit optio assumenda quidem reprehenderit qui veniam delectus aliquid ipsa? Magnam neque at corrupti aliquid, dolor possimus veniam, eum porro quasi non, impedit accusamus adipisci quis. Aliquam, neque quo dicta totam libero facere tempora eligendi obcaecati odit porro magni quos suscipit veniam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Odit optio assumenda quidem reprehenderit qui veniam delectus aliquid ipsa? Magnam neque at corrupti aliquid, dolor possimus veniam, eum porro quasi non, impedit accusamus adipisci quis. Aliquam, neque quo dicta totam libero facere tempora eligendi obcaecati odit porro magni quos suscipit veniam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Odit optio assumenda quidem reprehenderit qui veniam delectus aliquid ipsa? Magnam neque at corrupti aliquid, dolor possimus veniam, eum porro quasi non, impedit accusamus adipisci quis. Aliquam, neque quo dicta totam libero facere tempora eligendi obcaecati odit porro magni quos suscipit veniam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Odit optio assumenda quidem reprehenderit qui veniam delectus aliquid ipsa? Magnam neque at corrupti aliquid, dolor possimus veniam, eum porro quasi non, impedit accusamus adipisci quis. Aliquam, neque quo dicta totam libero facere tempora eligendi obcaecati odit porro magni quos suscipit veniam.</p>
</div>

<!-- Skills Section -->
<section class="skills">
  <div class="container-flex">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="heading">        
          <h2><span>HEADING 1</span></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <h3>Heading 3</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat. </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="right">      
      <!-- line bars-->
      <div class="line_content">
        <div class="line">
          <p>POINT 1</p>
          <div class="bar">
            <div class="line_bar point1"> </div>
          </div>
          <h5>95</h5>
        </div>    
        <div class="line">
          <p>POINT 2</p>
          <div class="bar">
            <div class="line_bar point2"></div>
          </div>
          <h5>80</h5>
        </div>    
        <div class="line">
          <p>POINT 3</p>
          <div class="bar">
            <div class="line_bar point3"> </div>
          </div>
          <h5>75</h5>
        </div>
      </div>       
      
      <!-- circle skill bars-->
      <div class="skill-container flex1">
        <div class="circle_box">
          <svg class="skill-circle" height=auto width=100%>
            <circle cx="-40" cy="10" r="48" style="stroke-dasharray: 289px;" transform="translate(50,50) rotate(-90)"></circle>
            <text id="text1" x="40" y="100" fill="#fff" font-family="Verdana" font-size="28">85</text>
          </svg>
          <h4>CIRCLE 1</h4>
        </div>    
        <div class="circle_box">
          <svg class="skill-circle" height=auto width=auto>
            <circle cx="-40" cy="10" r="48" style="stroke-dasharray: 214px;" transform="translate(50,50) rotate(-90)"></circle>
            <text id="text1" x="40" y="100" fill="#fff" font-family="Verdana" font-size="28">56</text>
          </svg>
          <h4>CIRCLE 2</h4>
        </div>    
        <div class="circle_box">              
          <svg class="skill-circle" height=auto width=auto>
            <circle cx="-40" cy="10" r="48" style="stroke-dasharray: 224px;" transform="translate(50,50) rotate(-90)"></circle>
            <text id="text1" x="40" y="100" fill="#fff" font-family="Verdana" font-size="28">60</text>
          </svg>
          <h4>CIRCLE 3</h4>
        </div>    
        <div class="circle_box">
          <svg class="skill-circle" height=auto width=auto>
            <circle cx="-40" cy="10" r="48" style="stroke-dasharray: 244px;" transform="translate(50,50) rotate(-90)"></circle>
            <text id="text1" x="40" y="100" fill="#fff" font-family="Verdana" font-size="28">70</text>
          </svg>
          <h4>CIRCLE 4</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

</body>

<script>
    const element = document.querySelector('.skill-container');
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
    element.classList.toggle( 'animation_circle', entries[0].isIntersecting );
    });
    observer.observe( element )
</script>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
  font-size: --main-font-size;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
}          

/*---------SKILLS SECTION--------*/
.container {
  max-width: 85%;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.container-flex {
  display: flex;  
}

.flex1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;  
}

.left, .right {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px;
}    

p {
  margin-top: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.left {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.right {
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.heading span {
  color: black;  
}

.heading {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.text h3{
  margin-bottom: 10px;     
}

.text p {
  margin-right: 50px;      
}

.skills {
  margin-top: 2%;
  min-height: 50vh;
}

.line_content .line {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.line_content p {
  width: 35%; 
  font-weight: 600;
}

.line_content h5 {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;      
  font-size: 12px;
}

.line_content h5 {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.line_content h5::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: -4px;
  top: 12px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: lightblue;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.line_content .line:nth-child(2) h5::after,
.line_content .line:nth-child(2) h5 {
  background: lightcoral;
}

.line_content .line:nth-child(3) h5::after,
.line_content .line:nth-child(3) h5 {
  background: lightgreen;
}
        
.line_content .bar {
  width: 60%;
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 5px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 20px;      
}

.line_content .line_bar {
  animation: bar 2.8s;
  height: 5px;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 95%;
}

.line_content .point2 {
  width: 80%;
  background: lightcoral;
}

.line_content .point3 {
  width: 75%;
  background: lightgreen;
}


@keyframes bar {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
}

@keyframes write {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }

  20% {
    content: "15%";
  }

  40% {
    content: "30%";
  }

  60% {
    content: "45%";
  }

  80% {
    content: "60%";
  }

  100% {
    content: "70%";
  }
}
    
.animation_bar {
  animation: bar 2.8s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
    
/*---------circle--------*/
@keyframes circle_animation {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 340px;
  }

  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
  }
}

.skill-container {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

circle {
  stroke-width: 5px;
  stroke: #D593FF;
  fill: transparent;
  animation: circle_animation 2s linear backwards;     
}

.skill-container .circle_box:nth-child(2) circle {
  stroke: darkgreen;    
}

.skill-container .circle_box:nth-child(3) circle {
  stroke: #FFA726;
}

.skill-container .circle_box:nth-child(4) circle {
  stroke: #00A0D2;
}

.skill-container .circle_box h4 {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.circle_box h4 {
  font-size: var(--main-font-size); 
  padding-left: 5px;
}

#text1 {
  vertical-align: middle;    
}

.skill-container.flex1{
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px; 
}
    
.animation_circle {
  animation: circle_animation 2s linear backwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `.line_content`? It's a class, so it needs the dot prefix within a selector

Comment: yes I have, but it does not change anything.